# ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() segfaulting with no augmentation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to construct an autoencoder for ultrasound images, and am unable to use `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` to provide train/test datasets due to segfault on call to the method.  No augmentation is being used, which should only result in the original images being provided by  the generator.

The source images are in TIFF format, so I first tried converting them to JPG and PNG thinking that maybe PIL was faulting on the encoding, no difference.  I have tried converting to different color modes (grayscale, RGB, RGBA) with no change in behavior.  I have stripped the code down to the bare minimum, taking defaults for nearly all function params and still getting a segfault on call in both debug and full run.

```py
# Directory below contains a single subdirectory "input" containing 5635 TIFF images
from keras.preprocessing.image import *

print('Create train_gen')
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    directory=r'/data/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/train/',
    class_mode='input'
)
print('Created train_gen')
```

Expected output is a report of 5635 images found in one class "input" and both debug messages to print out, with usable generator for use in `Model.fit_generator()`.

Actual output:

```sh
Using TensorFlow backend.
Create train_gen
Found 5635 images belonging to 1 classes.
Segmentation fault
```

Is there something I'm doing above that could be causing the problem?  According to every scrap of sample code I can find, it looks like it should be working.

Environment is:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- CUDA 10.1
- tensorflow-gpu 1.14
- Keras 2.2.4
- Python 3.7.2

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Run the python interpreter on a debugger and find out where it is crashing

Comment: I have, and it's crashing immediately on return from `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()`.  The `DirectoryIterator` obect is instantiated properly, and then when the return line is reached it segfaults with no exceptions or other explanation.  Running the intepreter with full verbosity yields nothing at that point either.

Comment: I should have been more clear, you have to run the python interpreter on a native debugger (like gdb or lldb) and get a stack trace, a python debugger will not provide relevant information.

Comment: OK, running under gdb I'm getting the following:
`
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000059afcd in PyObject_GC_Del ()
`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I haven't pegged *specifically* why it is segfaulting, but it appears to be related to the virtualenv it is running under. I was apparently using a JupyterHub environment, which seems to not behave even when run from an ssh session (vs from within JupyterHub consoles).  Once I created a whole new standalone virtualenv with only the TF + Keras packages installed, it appears to run just fine.